# How to trigger two cubit events at the click of a button and listen to the server's response?

Tags: flutter, rest, bloc, flutter-bloc, cubit

I'm trying to call two different functions when a button is clicked, but I couldn't figure out how to listen to the server response, based on the response I should do something.

I would like to understand how to manage the response of the API, because with BlocBuilder and with BlocListener I haven't succeeded. In fact, using the latter two, as soon as the BlocBuilder (or BlocListener) code is executed, the API in question is also called, and I don't want this! Because I want to call it during button click. I also tried with "buildWhen" and "listenWhen" but nothing, it doesn't seem to work!

I trust in you!

dialog.dart (_DialogState class)

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => {

//PROBLEM IS HERE, CATCHERROR NOT WORKING
                BlocProvider.of<InterventionCubit>(context).sendInvestigate(
                    widget.interventionId, {
                  'note': _problemController.text
                }).catchError((e) => print(e)),
                BlocProvider.of<InterventionCubit>(context).sendPhoto(
                    widget.interventionId, {
                  'photo': image
                }).catchError((e) => print(e)),
                _setIndex(1),
              },
              child: const Text(
                "Continua",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                      Theme.of(context).primaryColor)),
),
```

intervention_cubit.dart

```
class InterventionCubit extends Cubit<InterventionState> {
  InterventionCubit() : super(InterventionState.initial());
 Future<void> sendInvestigate(int interventionId, dynamic note) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(isLoading: true, success: false));
    try {
      final response = await ApiService.post(
          'interventions/$interventionId/investigate', note);
      if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
        if (kDebugMode) {
          //print("RESPONSE BODY RUNNING: " + response.body);
        }
        emit(state.copyWith(
            isLoading: false, success: true, response: response.body));
      } else {
        emit(state.copyWith(
          isLoading: false,
          success: false,
          errorMessage: "Errore durante l'invio della comunicazione",
        ));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      emit(state.copyWith(
        isLoading: false,
        success: false,
        errorMessage: "Errore durante la connessione",
      ));
    }
}
```

intervention_state.dart

```
class InterventionState {
  final bool isLoading;
  final String errorMessage;
  final dynamic response;
  final bool success;
  final String? token;
  InterventionState({
    required this.isLoading,
    required this.errorMessage,
    required this.response,
    required this.success,
    required this.token,
  });
  factory InterventionState.initial() {
    return InterventionState(
        response: {},
        isLoading: false,
        errorMessage: "",
        token: null,
        success: false);
  }
  InterventionState copyWith(
      {bool? isLoading,
      String? errorMessage,
      String? token,
      bool? success,
      Object? response}) {
    return InterventionState(
      response: response ?? this.response,
      success: success ?? this.success,
      isLoading: isLoading ?? this.isLoading,
      errorMessage: errorMessage ?? this.errorMessage,
      token: token ?? this.token,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is not exactly clear.


"...In fact, using the latter two, as soon as the BlocBuilder (or BlocListener) code is executed, the API in question is also called, and I don't want this!..."

what?
reformulate the question maybe